# Rails: create instance of model with nested attributes when a nested model already exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

I have two related models:

```
class Passenger < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :agency_order
  belongs_to :client

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :client
end

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :passengers

  validates :fio, presence: true

end
```

And I try create new passenger with existing client data:

```
  "1451936478618"=>{"client_attributes"=>{"fio"=>"пупкин илья петрович",
 "birthday"=>"09.06.2021",
 "passport"=>"",
 "phone"=>"",
 "id"=>"1"},
 "landing_places_id"=>"49",
 "seat"=>"",
 "bus_id"=>"",
 "_destroy"=>"0"}},
```

Passenger is nested model too. And in controller I got next error:

**Couldn't find Client with ID=1 for Passenger with ID=**

If I add new client all will save correctly.
What a right approach in this case?